# Getting NoSuchMethodError on HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManagerShared(true).build()

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-httpclient-4.x, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to create a HTTP connection with a URL in a EJB and the below line of code was throwing error

```
HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManagerShared(true).build();
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setConnectionManagerShared(Z)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
```

Initially I did not specify which version of HttpClient, so I added the GAV to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I ensured the war file had that jar. There was no error in Eclipse during compile time.

But whenever I execute it I am getting the NoSuchMethodError. I am using Java version 1.8.0_131.

I am totally confused because if I didn't get that error on compile time, why am I getting it on Runtime? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check that you server _libs_ directories don't contain another version of httpclient.

Comment: could you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is jar dependency problem. There are multiple jars available for this class in your code. Please check the jars which are using the package structure with below command and find out the culprit for that.

mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.http.impl.client

Comment: The -Dincludes should be [groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version] not Java package, so something like this works:
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient